# Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5. Searched in the following locations:

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

A colleague of mine, when trying to sync gradle, is getting the error below:

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5.
                    Searched in the following locations:
                    - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.pom
                    If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
                    Required by:
                    project :app > com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3
                    project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0 > com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:2.3.0 (48 s 278 ms)
```

We are running the same project and with the same version of Android Studio, 4.2.1. I'm not getting any errors on my machine but she seems to have a problem. Her OS is windows 10 and I'm using a mac.

I should mention that I've seen this thread: `https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1637` and followed the instructions here `https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/build.gradle`. However, it doesn't seem to solve the problem. Actually if it did I would be concerned since without changing the gradle file works for me.

Does anyone know what might be the issue here? Thank you.

Also I should mention, when I tried to click on the link in the error message, it's a dead link.

Comment: I am also having the same issue in my Android studio 4.2.2 version

Comment: We ended up uninstalling android studio and installed the beta version. Still ran into some issues but they were eventually solved. You may have to dig deeper into how to uninstall "everything" from android studio. Because it appears uninstalling from control panel in windows does not actually uninstall everything.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem after updating to 4.2.2.  - AS 4.2.2 display a code error: Cannot resolve symbol 'Gson' but the code compiles correctly and runs.